# How to disable and enable Div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can any one please tell me how to disable the following div?

```
<div class="continue-but submit">Submit</div>
```

I have tried

```
$('.submit').click(function () {
     $(".submit").prop('disabled', true);
     if (error >= 1) {
            // Errors
            $(".submit").prop('disabled', false);
            return false;
        } 
};
```

But there was no change. Can any one please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: How can you disable a textual `div`?

Comment: do you want to disable all the input fields in the div?

Comment: only `input`s can be disabled (mostly). Instead, you should remove the click handler from the div using `unbind('click')` and re-add it when it should be enabled again.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code to following

```
$('.submit').click(function () {
     var obj = $(this);
     obj.prop('disabled', true); 
     var originalonClick = obj.onclick; // storing current click handler 
     obj.onclick = function(){return false}; // updating click handler
     if (error >= 1) {
            // Errors
            $(".submit").prop('disabled', false);
            obj.onclick = originalonClick; // restoring click function
            return false;
        } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use preventDefault(); function, which ensures that click event will cancel out when you return false:

```
$('.submit').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".submit").prop('disabled', true);
     if (error >= 1) {
            // Errors
            $(".submit").prop('disabled', false);
            return false;
        } 
};
```